# Tensorflow: Training a model in C++

Tags: tensorflow

Can I train a model in C++ in Tensorflow? I don't see any optimizers exposed in it's C++ API. Are the optimizers written in Python? If not, how can I train a graph in C++? I'm able to import a Python trained graph in C++, but I want to write the code fully in C++ (training and inference)

Answer (score 1):

I have found an example training file from the official repository
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc

I do believe that this is only basic training of some sort, not open to all the optimizations that the python API has. I will keep looking around for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-differentiation is currently not implemented in C in tensorflow so training complex models in C is a huge task. They say they are working on it: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4130